# Why does DatePickerFragment return Null Object Reference when everything has been initialized

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch Guide 2nd edition for Android development.  I'm building a `DatePickerFragment` to pick a date.  The dialog launches through the `onClick` of a button.  Everything has been initialized.

`DatePickerFragment.java` class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this from `CrimeFragment.java` class

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ...

        mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();
                dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });

        ...
    }
```

As you can see, everything has been initialized (from what I can see) and yet I'm getting this error.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
                                                                               at myapp.onur.criminalintent.DatePickerFragment.<init>(DatePickerFragment.java:16)
                                                                               at myapp.onur.criminalintent.CrimeFragment$2.onClick(CrimeFragment.java:77)
```

Comment: share logcat @Onur

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace. Where are you facing the error? Or are you not getting date from date picker?

Comment: Its up there :) sorry about that guys.

Comment: You put this "v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);" 
inside onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState), Just declare private View v; at the begining.

Comment: @Debanjan Why is that an issue?

Comment: Do you need a custom view of your fragment? What view is there in R.layout.dialog_date

Comment: @kapsym Just a root view that is a DatePicker

Comment: I guess, since onAttach has not been called prior to 
View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null); hence, getActivity() returns null.

Comment: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture13/lecture13.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the view inflation to `onCreateDialog` like so:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `getActivity()` will only return a non-null value after `onAttach()` has been called. Consult [the Activity/Fragment lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) for details.

Answer (score -1):

add this :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, container, false);
        return v;
    }
```

so your code will be :

```
View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, container, false);
    return v;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
            .create();
}
```

Comment: But how would I set the layout as the view of my dialog?  Did you see the rest of my code?

Comment: you need to inflate the view inside the oncreate method

Comment: The problem with your code is that `onCreateDialog` only has access to the empty variable `View v;`.  So when I run it, I just get a dialog with a title and no calendar picker.

Comment: try to move the     v = inflater.from...; inside the oncreateDialog